# Excel: I copy pasted list 200 links from website to Excel and I want to extract text from the link

Tags: microsoft-excel

The links appear hyperlinked with blue line in Excel, I want to extract the text from the link e.g. The url http:\sea.craigslist.com appears as "seattle" in excel. I want to extract the text "sea" out of the link and paste in a next column.

Comment: could you clarify? you have a cell containing (blue-underlined) a link with TEXT="seattle" and LINK="http://sea.craigslist.com", right? you would like to extract "sea" from the TEXT or the LINK?

Answer (score 0):

This formula will pull out all text after the `http://` and before the first period, where `A1` is the cell containing the hyperlink. It's not an overly advanced method, but if *all* your data is in the same, simple, format this may be sufficent.

```
=MID( A1 , SEARCH("http://",A1)+7 , SEARCH(".",A1)-SEARCH("http://",A1)-7 )
```

**However**, this relies on the hyperlink URL being the visible text, and doesn't work when they are showing thier friendly name. In otherwords it doesn't work when the hyperlink is showing as just "Seattle", because the formula works on that instead of the URL.

So far, I cannot find a way around this issue without resorting to a custom VBA function - in which case the entire thing may as well be a custom function. Would this be an acceptable solution?

Alternatively, does anyone know of a built-in function to extract the link's target?

Comment: it could be done by defining a function in VBA (see [link](http://www.bohack.com/2009/06/get-the-url-from-a-hyperlink-in-excel/))

Comment: @Wilson, quite, as per my 3rd paragraph. And it's a very simple function indeed, even if you built it to also extract the subdomain as well. But people often seem to dislike using custom functions, hence my hesitation in offering it as the main thrust of my answer.

Comment: actually i dislike custom function as well. :) but i just found that reference and share it here. seems that there is no equivalent built-in function.